# imprimir hasta el primer salto de linea

Tags: string

Tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
WORLDQUERY SPA
RUT:76.657.509-9
VENTAS AL POR MENOR DE BEBIDAS
```

¿Cómo puedo imprimir desde RUT hasta el final, es decir:

```
RUT:76.657.509-9
```

Estoy usando

```
rut = 'RUT'
rut_proveedor = text.index(rut)
print(text[rut_proveedor:rut_proveedor+16])
```

pero no siempre va a terminar en esa posición

Comment: ¿Y eso en que lenguage de programación lo estás haciendo?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Puedes utilizar expresiones regulares (Regex, del inglés [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html))

```
import re
s = """WORLDQUERY SPA
RUT:76.657.509-9
VENTAS AL POR MENOR DE BEBIDAS"""
print(re.search('(RUT[^\n]+)', s)[0])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
RUT:76.657.509-9
```

Otra opción (Si no quieres importar ningún módulo) sería utilizar `split()` para dividir el `string` en filas y únicamente obtener fila con índice 1

```
s = """WORLDQUERY SPA
RUT:76.657.509-9
VENTAS AL POR MENOR DE BEBIDAS"""

print(s.split('\n')[1])
```

Esto devuelve:

```
RUT:76.657.509-9
```